# Exporting Illustrator objects to svg showing up as 3 separate icons in ICOMOON

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, export, svg

I have created a simple icon and have exported it for use in ICOMOON. The developer is stating that it is showing up as three separate icons.

[image: IcoMoonissue]

They are grouped and I have even placed them in one layer. I usually use Sketch, but they have a bug right now during this kind of function, so I am using Illustrator. I have followed directions, about the export. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem, what I discovered was that Iconmoon requires all your exported SVG shapes to be compound paths. ie. masked shapes NOT grouped shapes.

A group is not a compound path, it is a collection of parts that make a whole. I don't use illustrator anymore, but here is a link that will help you understand the difference.

**Illustrator Compund Paths:**

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/combining-objects.html